# What happened to Neo in the last part of the Matrix trilogy?

Tags: the-matrix

What happened to Neo in the last part of trilogy when the machine gave him the power to battle with Agent Smith. Was he dead?

Comment: hey,I also want to know that Is neo dead in the real life too,since the matrix is a hypothetical world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neo was effectively the result of a 'Glitch', which is why he was able to achieve impossible things whilst inside the progam. He was able to bypass it's restrictions, and render it's security and protection meaningless (as if the Hacker occupation wasn't subtle enough a clue).

Agent Smith was the result of the Matrix automatically trying to correct this Glitch through balance; much like a human immune system creating anti-bodies to attack a virus, which in theory is what Neo had become.

The Matrix *NEEDED* Agent Smith in order to 'balance it's spreadsheet', so to speak..

If Neo was defeated by the Anti-bodies (Smith), there is no longer any need for those anti-bodies to exist and so the Matrix will automatically restore the balance by deleting Smith.

The agreement made by Neo and the Source (an expression of the Matrix's interface) was one of appeasement, not surrender. He would effectively sacrifice himself for a ceasefire agreement with Zion.

The idea that the Matrix is of an intrinsically self-balancing, auto-correcting nature is actually sowed in the first film, during Smith's 'Equilibirium' speech.

I guess they call that Foreshadowing...

Comment: And to the second part; I think yes, he is dead in real life too, unfortunately. It's implied that total Kinesis is achieved through logging into the Matrix, and that the brain is unable to process virtual death without resulting in accompanying brain-death. That being said, he's always pulled off one resurrection...
There's a certain ambiguity of such things that adds to the mythology of the Matrix itself, and think it's very much by design...

Answer (score 4):

Is Neo dead? 
Neo was previously able to transfer his mind to Mobil Ave without a hardwire.
Sati and Oracle talks at the end:

> Oracle: Did you do that? 
>  
>   Sati: *nods* **For** Neo. 
>   Oracle: That's nice. I know
>   **he'd** love it. 
>   Sati: Will we ever **see him again?** 
>   Oracle: **I suspect so.
>   Someday.**

Answer (score 3):

No. If you watch carefully, they needed Smith to absorb Neo - when that happened, only THEN did the machines/Architect gain power over Smith (via Neo's jacked-in body) and delete Smith.

While Neo was alive during the battle, but there's no telling what happened in the aftermath. Seems that he died when he was consumed by Smith and the connection to the Matrix was unplugged, but there's no clear canon confirmation of that.

Comment: Poor Neo...it seems that he had the same purpose (antivirus) and the same fate (locked indefinitely in a virtual box) as Halman at the end of *3001: The Final Odyssey*.

Comment: I interpreted it to mean that Smith no longer had any purpose, and since his purpose was in part to remove software that no longer had any purpose, he deleted himself. Probably completely against his will, because he doesn't have any free will. But Neo had to *die* for this to happen, because Smith's purpose was to kill Neo. Therefore he's dead. And so is Smith.