# Why did the machines need Neo's help at the end of the third movie?

Tags: the-matrix

Title says it all, really. Just rewatched the trilogy and I really don't understand why they needed Neo's help to deal with Smith.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did Neo die in the end of the Matrix trilogy?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/did-neo-die-in-the-end-of-the-matrix-trilogy) (and this; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38611/what-happened-to-neo-in-the-last-part-of-the-matrix-trilogy)

Comment: This questions asks *why* did *the machines* "need Neo's help". How on Earth is this a duplicate of whether *did* at the end *Neo* "die" - seems two totally different question the only common both being about matching set of scenes.

Comment: @naxa Read the top answer on that question.

Comment: @Keen, okay I admit this seem to get on my hobby horse. I've read that *question* + body. 'Incorrect' answers or 'incorrect' accepts do not constitute in my opinion, but this is a meta topic. But I fear stackexchange becoming an increasingly random mess of 'related theory **discussion** interlinking' (just like ordinary forums tend to), this way. The two *questions* being different should be enough.